# Files and Directories inside Access Database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I'm working on a program which contains a directory like ( Major directories and each directory contains sub directories and each sub directory contain sub2 directories and so on ... till final directory contains .doc files as objects.)
**Example:**
[image]

How can i design the data base to accept this tree hierarchy then i can get each directories and open any .doc in my c# program.

I'm a beginner in using tree-view and database.

Thanks

**Edit:**

I have 7 main folders and each folder has a number of sub-folders and may be some sub-folders1 have another sub-folders2 which contain files, other sub-folders1 have files too. ( All files are 10000 almost).

**QUESTION:**

How i populate this structure into database then i can list them in treeview or listbox ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for a unlimited level infinite structure with just one table. I will be using MS SQL here. But same logic would apply to MS Access as well.

[image]

Id is the unique identifier of the row.
ParentId is the reference to Id where this row will appear under. In other words, Parent of the current row.
Name is the field for containing directory or file name.
IsFile (can be omitted) is to determine if this is a file or directory. You can actually apply some logic in the code to check if the row has any children. If there are children of this row, you can simply mark it as a directory.

Then we can populate this table with some data

[image]

If you were using MS SQL Server 2005 and onwards, you could simply create a CTE (Common Table Expression) to make the whole tree automatically. But Access does not support common table expressions.

As you tagged C# in the question, you should use C# to create a recursive function to call itself if the item has children.

```js
PopulateMenu();

private void PopulateMenu()
{
  var parentItems = GetMenuItemsWhereParentIdIsNull();
  foreach(var item in parentItems)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(item["Name"]);
    PopulateChildrenByItem(item);
  }
}

private void PopulateChildrenByItem(object item)
{
  var childItems = GetMenuItemsByParentId(item["Id"]);
  foreach(var item in childItems)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Child Item: " + item["Name"]);
    
    //Recursively check for children of this child item
    PopulateChildrenByItem(item["Id"]);
  }
}

function object GetMenuItemsWhereParentIdIsNull()
{
  //code for getting the parent items from access via ado.net
  //query should be something like "SELECT * FROM Menu WHERE ParentId IS NULL"
}

function object GetMenuItemsByParentId(int Id)
{
  //code for getting the child items by given parentId from access via ado.net
  //query should be something like "SELECT * FROM Menu WHERE ParentId = <Id>"
}
```

Note that PopulateChildrenByItem is calling itself to check for child items of the iterated item.

I hope this will guide you to the right direction

Cheers

Comment: Folders have more than 10000 word documents

Comment: It should not be a problem with the parent-child structure. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: can 1 table has all this files without error ?

Comment: Only limitation would be the size of Access database as you are limited to maximum 2 GB minus the space for objects. I have a procurement solution which holds more than 500k documents in a tree structure with only one table.

Comment: I'll try this solution - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in a tree you might have a look at this:

**Classes**

```
public class FolderEntry {

    public string Name {
      get; set;
    }

    public List<FolderEntry> FolderEntries {
      get; set;
    }

    public List<FileEntry> Files {
      get; set;
    }


  }


  public class FileEntry {

    public string Name {
      get; set;
    }

    public string FileType {
      get; set;
    }

  }
```

**DataBase-Design:**

[image: Database]

This is not a full solution, but something you can start with.
To fill the classes with data, i suggest you to implement a RepositoryPattern

Comment: I'm tried this concept but i can't understand classes and Folders_FKIndex1 ?

Comment: A tree is recursive structure. So a node can have a node and so on. A file is **always** in a folder. So Files and Folders have a strong relation marked with an ForeignKey (FK)

Comment: Understand now -- Thanks